# SupportMapFragment in ListView header

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am working with `Fragment` based application and need to use Google Maps API v2 for showing the map. I am trying to get `SupportMapFragment` into `ListView` header and not sure how to achieve that.

I've tried creating `newInstance` of fragment and calling `getView` to be set as headerView, but `getView` is returning me null.

This doesn't work:

```
SupportMapFragment s = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
list.addHeaderView(s.getView());
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't really get what you are trying to do, could you show your code?

Comment: I want map to be attached into ListView header.

Comment: never really tried to do that but, for what i know you are using a fragment here and not a simple view... and I don't know if it's possible to do what you want. and what is the goal? just put a map fragment in your upper side of the screen and your listview below it..

Comment: The goal is simple, I want map to scroll with the list, that's why I want it to be in the header...

Comment: but if it's in the header, then it's fixed and it's not scrolling with the list.

Comment: Header view in a ListView is not fixed. It scrolls along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by defining the fragment in own xml file, inflating that view and adding that as header view.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use getView() on the new instance like this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag=SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
View listHeaderView = mapFrag.getView();
listView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```

Comment: Isn't mapFrag.getView() null here? I'm pretty sure it is, but even if it's not, you might not have many things that map fragment offers. For example, loading the map images might be activated in onStart not in onCreateView. I haven't looked at map fragment source code, but fragments are more than just a view, you shouldn't be using them like this.